# MVC CRUD Edit and Delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making an MVC project with basic CRUD functionalities.

In the Index view I have the standard edit and delete links. Which can be clicked for each content item.

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ContentItemID })>
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ContentItemID })
</td>
```

While this works fine. I want the edit and delete link to be an icon instead of just plain text. I have tried a couple of things but all of them deleted the `new { id = item.ContentItemID }`
Which I do need to have in my edit and delete so I can select a specific item to edit or delete.

I would like to use the font awesome `<i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size:22px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and the `<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size:22px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Is there a possibility for me to do this?

Comment: You cannot using `@Html.ActionLink()` Instead use `<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.ContentItemID })"><i .....></i></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Actionlink is just a generated URL , you can for example concatenate it as an alternative , something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName/" + @item.ContentItemID)"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size:22px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Html.ActionLink` just generates an `<a>` tag for you. So you can use `Url.Action` for generating the link.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.ContentItemID })> 
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size:22px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ActionLink automatically encodes the text you specify. You can implement your own version of that methods that *doesn't* encode, and keep using the HtmlHelper. This is more reliable than concatenating, since this will not work if routes change in the future.

You can find a sample implementation [here](http://rickvandenbosch.net/blog/how-to-create-an-actionlink-with-a-twitter-bootstrap-icon-in-mvc4/).